# Absolute continuity, shifted set

Tags: measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-measure

> Let $\mu$ be a finite signed measure on the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$, and suppose that $\mu \ll m$ where $m$ is Lebesgue measure.  Prove that the function $t\mapsto \mu\{t+x:x\in A\}$ is continuous in $t$ for every Borel set $A$.

**An Attempt:**
Using the sequence definition of continuity and writing $\mu(A)=\int f(x)dm$ as an integral and using the fact that Lebesgue measure is shift invariant I get to where I want to switch limits with integration as well as show that $f(x+t_n)\to f(x+t)$ where $t_n\to t$.  This last bit seems especially suspicious since we don't know much about $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that we may not have $f(x+t_n)\to f(x+t)$ when $t_n\to t$. However, what is true (and sufficient to conclude) is that if $t_n\to t$, then $\int_{\mathbb R}\left|f(x+t_n)-f(x+t)\right|\mathrm d\lambda(x)\to 0$ (to see this, approximate in $\mathbb L^1(\lambda)$ the function $f$ by a continuous function with compact support).

Comment: Say I approximate in $L^1$, I get to a point where I want to switch limits again to be able to use that the approximate functions are continuous.   Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. If $\mu\ll m$, then there exists a function $g\in L^1(\mathbb R)$, such that
$d\mu=g\,dm$. Clearly,
$$
f(t)=\mu(t+x: x\in A)=\int_Af(x-t)\,dm(x).
$$
Then
$$
\lvert f(s)-f(t)\rvert\le \int_A\lvert\, g(x-s)- g(x-t)\rvert\,dm(x)
\le \int_{\mathbb R}\lvert\, g(x-s)- g(x-t)\rvert\,dm(x)
=\|T_{t-s}g- g\|_{L^1}
$$
where $(T_ag)(x)=g(x-a)$. It is true that $\lim_{h\to 0}\|T_{h}g- g\|_{L^1}=0$.

Comment: Is that last statement clear?  Sorry.

Comment: Write $f(t)=\int_A g(x-t)dm(x)=(g*\chi_A)(t)$ as a convolution.  Though I can't find a source, I think we have enough conditions to say that convolutions of that type are continuous; hence the result.